Angular with Jest and ECM Module does not work
I used the code from following site to test an example with Angular 17 and Jest for unit tests:
https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular/tree/main/examples/example-app-v17
After running npm test, everything is fine and the tests are finished without an issue.
Because I have to use the library jsonpath-plus, I changed the implementation of examples\example-app-v17\src\app\app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterLink, RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { JSONPath } from 'jsonpath-plus';
import { BannerComponent } from './banner/banner.component';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './welcome/welcome.component';

@Component({
    standalone: true,
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    imports: [BannerComponent, WelcomeComponent, RouterOutlet, RouterLink],
})
export class AppComponent {
    static check(): any {
        const path = `$..*[?(@property === 'className')]^^^`;

        const object: any = JSONPath({
            path,
            json: []
        });

        return object;
    }
}

After starting the test via npm test, I got the following error:

Also with the given hints, I was not able to fix this issue.
How can I fix this?

I fixed it by mocking the module as shown here
jest.mock('jsonpath-plus', () => ({
    JSONPath: jest.fn().mockImplementation((query: any) => {
        return [];
    })
}));

